# String to list index out of range

Tags: c#

When I try to run my program I get this:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Arg_ParamName_Name"

```
static List<string> strToList(string s)
{
    // input = 00:00:00AM
    //         0123456789
    List<string> a = new List<string> { };
    a.Add(s.Substring(0, 2)); //hh [0]  
    a.Add(s.Substring(3, 5));    //mm [1]
    a.Add(s.Substring(6, 8)); //ss [2]
    a.Add(s.Substring(8, 10)); //am [3]

    return a;
}



string s = "12:01:00PM";

List<string> a = strToList(s);

foreach (var x in a) {
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: It should be `s.Substring(8, 2)`, not `s.Substring(8, 10)`: the second parameter is *length*, not *index*. Same for `s.Substring(3, 2)`, `s.Substring(6, 2)`

Comment: You probably want to verify the length of `s` at the start of `strToList`. Consider something like `DateTime.TryParse` (or `.TryParseExact`) to turn the string into a valid DateTime and then extracting the parts from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substing([index],[length])

```
static List<string> strToList(string s)
    {
        // input = 00:00:00AM
        //         0123456789
        List<string> a = new List<string> { };
        a.Add(s.Substring(0, 2)); //hh [0]  
        a.Add(s.Substring(3, 2));    //mm [1]
        a.Add(s.Substring(6, 2)); //ss [2]
        a.Add(s.Substring(8, 2)); //am [3]

        return a;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument is the length of the string you want to retrieve.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_

So `s.Substring(0,3)` takes the first three characters. (starting at index 0)
`s.Substring(2,5)` takes 5 characters starting at index 2.